# Embedding version control information returns error when file is not under version control

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

Consider the following MWE. Note that this uses Mercurial for illustrative purposes, but the question is not specific to Mercurial

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}

\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
  \input{"| hg log -v -l 1 \jobname.tex --template '{node}  {date|isodate}'"}\\
}
\end{document}
```

If the file is under version control, then the command

```
hg log -v -l 1 \jobname.tex --template '{node}  {date|isodate}'
```

has a non-empty value, and then there is no problem. However, if the file is under version control, then this command does not return a value, and the file reduces to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}

\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
  \\
}
\end{document}
```

which gives an error. What is a good way of ensuring that if the string returned by input is empty, then the `\\` should be removed?

A different command could be used instead of the `hg` one. The only requirement is that under some conditions it return nothing.

Comment: What it the hg tag for?

Comment: @karlkoeller See update.

Comment: @karlkoeller what is the rationale for indenting the code 8 spaces instead of 4?

Comment: I don't know. It's you that are indenting it with 8 spaces (it is needed when inside a list, but not here)

Comment: Note that this command will not necessarily return nothing if a file is not under version control. Although it probably returns nothing on standard out, it will return something to standard error. It would probably be better to use a wrapper which would check for this and explicitly return nothing.

Comment: @cfr I'm unclear why it would return something on standard error. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What I mean is that the `hg...` command will return something to standard error, even when it returns nothing to standard out. I don't know exactly how the `\input... |` works, but I assume that basically it is redirecting standard out to TeX's input stream. So, unless you were to explicitly request it, standard error won't be similarly re-directed. But the command still outputs to standard error. There are always (normally?) 3 streams: input; standard out; standard error. If a command is successful, there should be only standard out. ...

Comment: ... If not, a well-designed command will output something helpful to standard error. At a terminal line, you typically get both together by default - both standard out and standard error are redirected to the terminal by the shell. You can change this either on the command line or in a script or whatever. And sometimes commands might not give anything, even though they fail. But that's poor design. (It is different if success returns no output - that's often fine. But failure should - and usually does - return something.)

Comment: The `hg` command does not output anything to standard error when it returns nothing to standard output. Maybe for completeness it would be a good idea to deal with standard error, but I don't even have a good idea how the `|` command works. Does it typeset standard output as well as standard error?

Comment: Please suggest additional suitable tags, or just edit the question. Thank you.

Comment: Best would not be to use `\\ ` at all and just have a blank line. Or the end of the `\parbox` if there really is nothing following.

Comment: There's additional text in the `\parbox` after the `\\ `. I left it out for simplicity. Should I add something?

Comment: `hg` certainly outputs stuff to standard error for me in a range of cases when nothing is output to standard output. You are presumably not testing outside a versioned directory. (I don't know if that's the term - for subversion I'd say outside a working copy.)

Comment: @cfr Ah, good point. Yes, I'm only testing inside a versioned directory. I have a `~/.hg` directory at the top of my home directory. So my entire home is nominally inside a hg working directory. So, what is your recommendation?

Comment: Well, if it will never happen to you, maybe you can just ignore it. You don't need robustness re. a particular issue if the problem doesn't apply to you.

Comment: @cfr Well, I wouldn't mind knowing of a more general solution/approach.

Comment: Well, you have to decide what should happen. You can redirect standard error the same way you can redirect standard output. How exactly depends on the shell. And you can catch the exit code and test it, too. So you can do what you want, but you have to decide what you want ;). But to be clear: I'd do this in the shell and then feed back something meaningful to the compiler which would then act appropriately (output a warning? output a message? fail with an error? typeset the error text?). Or you can send the standard error to nowhere if you don't care about it.

Comment: That is, you can redirect the standard error to nowhere as opposed to not handling it.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I'd probably throw away the standard error.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Then send it to `/dev/null`, assuming that is nowhere on your system. You can still catch the exist code if you wish, but there's no point unless it makes a difference to what you do next.

Comment: I'm not sure how that code would look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could test for hmode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}

\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
 % your input ...
 \ifhmode  \\  \fi 
  blalal
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but I don't know why. Apparently `% your input` is processed if TeX is in one of the horizontal modes, and otherwise is ignored. But why does blank input imply that it leaves horizontal mode?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: the "%your comment"  is only a comment, I left out your command as it is not relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what your comment is saying. I'm in chat, if you prefer to answer there.

Comment: I simply added a test around the ` \\ ` which checks if the paragraph has already started.